# How do I configure node modules search paths (for require()) in Code Runner for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, visual-studio-code, npm

I have recently started Javascript course & I configured my Visual studio code to run js.

Below is the code which I wrote

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
var fname = prompt("First name please :");
var lname = prompt("last name please :");
console.log("Your name is ",fname,lname);
```

I configured my VS code by installing Code Runner and also executing command `npm install prompt-sync` , however my code is throwing below list of long errors.

[image]

However if I try to run same code via cmd, it runs fine

[image]

Below are my npm and nodejs version
[image]

Can anyone please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Note:- I am storing and saving all my js files in a folder on local disk `D`

Comment: Please confirm if you're using Visual Studio 2017/2019/2022, or Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Sorry , it is actually Visual studio code

Comment: Where did you run npm install?

Comment: I have installed nodejs and with that npm was also installed. I checked that via cmd

Comment: Your `Desktop` folder is not the same location as `D:\Source Code\JavaScript\Input.js`. It looks like you're running completely different files.

Comment: It looks like you are missing the `prompt-sync` package/module, to fix that in your project directory run `npm install prompt-sync` or `yarn add prompt-sync` depending what you use at the start of your project

Comment: @RicardoSanchez The OP _does_ have `prompt-sync` installed _somewhere_ (otherwise the second screenshot would show an error). The question is why `node` doesn't see the installed modules when run from VSC's Code Runner window.

Comment: Yes, file location of `desktop` and `D:\Source Code\JavaScript\Input.js` is different. I have 2 copies of same file , copied  from D folder to desktop to easily run via cmd.

Comment: @Dai My bad, He did mention the installed package step

Comment: I have changed one of your question tags. You were using the [[tag:cmd]] tag, but your problem is not with cmd.exe. If you take a look at your own error image, it is clear that your code is running in powershell.exe instead. As nobody has yet mentioned that, possibly very important fact, I thought I should follow up the tag change to inform you all.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**

```
cd d:\Source-code\JavaScript
npm init -y
npm i
```

*changed Source code dir's name*

Comment: How is this a solution to the OP's problem? Instructing them to rename a directory to avoid having spaces is not a real solution.

Comment: Already tried removing space that does not work.Moreover there are other js files in same directory which do not requite user input and they run perfectly  even if directory name has spaces.

Comment: Windows seperate arguments with space so i make -

Comment: You tried other thing?

Comment: Yes, I tried everything but nothing worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).